# Disable if, for, while, etc. outlining in Visual Studio 2017 for C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've noticed that Visual Studio 2017 automatically outlines C# block statements unlike Visual Studio 2015. I couldn't find a setting for this. Is there any way to disable it?

Comment: What do you mean by outlines? Oh do you mean the collapsable +/- on the left?

Comment: As the several answers demonstrate, it's unclear which of several features you are referring to.  This is a case where adding a screenshot (or at least more description) would help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit tab --> Outlining --> Stop Outlining.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are describing Structure Guidelines which are a new feature enabled by default in Visual Studio 2017.

According to [this MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/03/06/productivity-power-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/):

> You can enable and disable this feature in Tools->Options. Look for
>   “Show structure guide lines” under Display in the Text Editor options
>   page.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it using

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced

Then untick enable outlining as shown in image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you looking at the "guide lines"

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> General -> Show structure guide lines

[image]

BUT, I generally find this useful. Do you really want to turn this off ?

Answer (score 0):

Just moved to VS 2017 and I believe the answer to this is that when you collapse all of your code, 2017 also now includes items in each method such as [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFwTC.jpg)

to change this you need to go to Tools > Options > Test Editor > C#/Basic > Advanced and uncheck Show Outlining for Code Level Construct.  [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuBkg.jpg)